# TextView not adding in fragment layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a master-detail activity with fragments. I try to add `TextView` dynamically in detail fragment. But it's not adding to detail fragment layouts. But the layouts are displayed properly.

**Fragment code:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_configuration_detail, container, false);
    RelativeLayout cdf_detail_part1=((RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(
            R.id.cdf_detail_part1));

    Log.i("config", "mItem1->"+mItem1);
    if (mItem1 != null) {
        TextView name_text = (TextView) cdf_detail_part1.findViewById(
                R.id.cdf_tv_name);
        name_text.setText(name);
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

**My layout XMl file:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.x.y.configurations.ConfigurationDetailFragment" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cdf_detail_part1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00FF00" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cdf_tv_name"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

      </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cdf_detail_part2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:background="#0000FF" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe the condition `mItem1` is `null` and the condition result is `false`

Comment: TextView name_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(
                R.id.cdf_tv_name); instead

Comment: mitem is not null..it is having value..

Comment: ok try declaring view textview and relative layout with bore accesebility ie: public r global and try debugging so you can know wether the find view by id returns a null or not

Comment: no textview also not null...tried TextView name_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.cdf_tv_name); It displays only on eText view.But i have mulitple text view. It is diaplys only first textview.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it may have something to do with the RelativeLayout and the attributes set there. Try using a LinearLayout for id cdf_detail_part1. RelativeLayout is quite tricky to use, LinearLayout is much easier. So if you can get it to work with LinearLayout, you can try to translate it back to a RelativeLayout.

Comment: I solved this issue. I added layout_width=match_parent to all Text views. So one text view hides other text views.Now it works fine.Thank You